# Call Userform when a certain parameter is not met using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am currently working on an excel sheet where I am trying to basically have a userform appear once my If...Then Statement is true. My "If, Then" statement bascially consists of the data point being above the maximum or below the minimum.

Once the data point meets those parameters, that is when I want to call the Userform. I am trying to have the Userform to display an entry for a number and once entered, it will make sure that it is not above the maximum or below the minimum. Then if it is not above the maximum or below the minimum, I would want to submit that number that was entered into the cell where the user inputted the data. I know it may seem simple but I am fairly new to VBA and I am trying my best to learn it. So far with the UserForm I got up to designing it. So I just entered text and and entry box. That is about it. Thank you for the Help!

Also here is my code that I have for the "If, Then" Statement. I orginially had it where it sends an email. So after the "Then" term. I made the macro send an email to the owner of that excel sheet. I am trying to use this code as well to make the UserForm:

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub OutofControl()
Dim lRow        As Long
Dim lstRow      As Long
Dim data As Variant
Dim ul As Variant
Dim ll As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws          As Worksheet


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True


End With

Set ws = Sheets(2)
ws.Select


lstRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)

For lRow = 1 To lstRow

data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value
ul = Range("K26")
ll = Range("K25")

    If data > ul Or data < ll Then

    If IsNumeric(data) = True And data Like "" = False Then

' Code for Sending Email after Then
```

Now Here is my code on the Sheet with the Selection Change After I did some research. However I am getting an infinite loop and the Input box is not entering the data I type. Also the "Run OutofControl" line in the code refers to another macro that sends out an automatic email.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim lRow        As Long
Dim lstRow      As Long
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim data As Variant
Dim ul As Variant
Dim ll As Variant
Dim ws          As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets(2)
ws.Select

lstRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)

For lRow = 1 To lstRow

data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value
ul = Range("K26")
ll = Range("K25")


    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("E:E")


    If (data > ul) Or (data < ll) Then

         Application.EnableEvents = False
    If IsNumeric(data) = True And data Like "" = False Then

     Run ("OutofControl") 'Macro
      Application.EnableEvents = False


        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.

        Application.EnableEvents = True

        On Error GoTo 0

        MsgBox ("There was an Out of Control Point at " & Cells(lRow, "C").Value)
       Teststr = InputBox("Enter your Control data:")

         End If
    End If


    Next lRow



End Sub
```

Comment: You need to do some research on worksheet events, specifically the `OnChange` event.

Comment: So here is my code for the OnChange event. However I am getting an infinite loop and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier to do this with a `InputBox`!

```
TestStr = InputBox("Enter your data:")
'If... Then conditions
Range("Cell Name").Value = TestStr
```

Then test that string against your parameters.
EDIT: Updated for new criteria:

```
Dim StrPrompt As String
Dim TestStr As Long

StrPrompt = "How many data?"
redo:
TestStr = Application.InputBox(StrPrompt, "Enter an integer number (numbers will be rounded)", , , , , , Type:=1)
If TestStr > ul or lngNum < ll Then
    StrPrompt = "How many data - this must be between " & ll & " and " & ul
    GoTo redo
End If
Cells(lRow, "E").Value = TestStr
```

Comment: Hello Chrismas 007 you have helped me so much thank you! Also I tried your code and it works. I just used Dim TestStr as String and it works but the thing is that when I enter the data its not chaning in the cell that showed up. What code do I have to enter to place it in the cell that met the criteria of my "If Then" Statement?

Comment: `Range("Cell name").Value = TestStr`

Comment: For the Range("Cell Name").Value = TestStr how do I specify the cell that had the conditions that met the If. Then Conditions?

Comment: Would that be this cell `data = Cells(lRow, "E").Value`?  If so then just flip it `Cells(lRow, "E").Value = TestStr`

Comment: Wow what a Coincidence. When I changed it. I just saw your comment. I fixed that . However , how can I make the Input Box see if the data that the user is entering is not above the maximum or below the minumum? I basically want it to make it require that they enter the correct data and they cannot proceed entering data until they have the correct data entered(i.e. not above the maximum and not below the minumum, it will be in that range?) Sorry for asking so many questions. You have been truly helping me out @Chrismas007 !

Comment: I tried the edit. So I made some changes but it works now! I just changed the Test Str to Variant. It works now! How would I make it so that when someone enters a data point that is above maximum or below minimum . the input box will show up?

Comment: Put the code after `If (data > ul) Or (data < ll) Then Application.EnableEvents = False If IsNumeric(data) = True And data Like "" = False Then`